# Referencing data in MYSQL database on Wordpress Site

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I have a basic table in a wordpress site that looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4fcpdgs8/

Right now the table is hard coded with values found in the html but ideally I would like it to be dynamic based on the values in the MYSQL database.  I have seen some solutions that involve php such as:

```php
global $wpdb;
// this adds the prefix which is set by the user upon instillation of wordpress
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "your_table_name";
// this will get the data from your table
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name" );
?>
<ul>
foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){ ?>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->another_column_name;?></li>
<li><?php echo $retrieved_data->as_many_columns_as_you_have;?></li>
<?php 
}
?>
</ul>
<?php
```

But one wrinkle is that one column is a url for an html image tag so doing the above just displays the url.

So, I would rather do something that would enable me to just ***reference*** the sql results like:

```html
<img src=[mysql_image_column_row_one]>
<img src=[mysql_image_column_row_two]>
```

Rather than just displaying the sql results in a table.  Sidenote: I know very little php and it is quite mysterious to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  use this for images

```
<?php  echo '<img name="myimage" src=' .  $retrieved_data->column_name 
. ' width="60" height="60" alt="imagedesciription" />'?>;
```

You must adept the image size  or even resize the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use img tag with an image path inside li tag in foreach loop.

```
<li><img src='path_to_image_folder/<?php echo $retrieved_data->image_name?>'></li>
```